Cannot make tensorflow and cuda work togheter
I have a conda envoronment with Python 3.8.18, tensorflow Version: 2.13.0, if I run nvcc --version I get this:

and if I run nvidia-smi I get this:

But then, if I run this command:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
the result will be:

why do I get this result? all the versions should be ok one with each other
